# Как составить уравнение прямой проходящей через несколько точек

Tags: математика

Есть ось координатов x,y. На ней три точки. Возможно ли составить уравнение "прямой" проходящей через эти три точки?

Comment: А если точки не на одной прямой?

Comment: В общем случае нет. Но если это экспериментальные точки и задача провести прямую, которая обеспечивает минимальное отклонение от экспериментальных данных... но это - совсем другая история. Кстати, а почему вы "прямой" взяли в кавычки? Может, вы вкладываете в это понятие что-то отличное от прямой?

Comment: @nomnoms12 И как вы ее примените к *трем* точкам? Где доказательство? Я могу предложить геометрию, в которой ваша аксиома будет справедлива, но через 3 точки можно будет провести прямую...

Comment: @Harry Забудьте это, пожалуйста :) Я сказал какую-то глупость

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если построить прямую проходящую через две точки то выясняется что, в случае если третья прямая лежит на построенной, то собственно прямая существует и единственна, это вроде очевидно. Так же несложно понять, что если взять любые 2 из 3 данных точек в случае если они лежат на одной прямой то будет получаться та же прямая. Иначе говоря, уравнение возможно составить по любым двум точкам и проверить по этому уравнению лежит ли третья точка на этой прямой или нет. Уравнение для двух точек выглядит так:

[image: уравнение прямой]

С помощью трёх точек можно построить плоскость, но это другая история полагаю.

Comment: картинка не загружается

Comment: @qwabra исправил, спасибо.